# Sharepoint Calendar interaction with Lotus notes calendar

Tags: calendar

Can anybody help me how to connect sharepoint 2010 calendar to lotus notes calendar? Means if we add something in Sharepoint calendar that should reflect in lotus notes calendar.

Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've not seen any 3rd party tools that do that specifically so you would need to create custom code on the SharePoint side that can interface with the Notes API.  Most likely you would want to do this with an event receiver, but you may be able to do it with a workflow as well, though it would be a little trickier and would still require custom code.

Comment: Thank you MIKE.  But I am very new to Lotus notes, I want to know whether I need an intermediate format like XML to transform Calendar list item to lotus notes calendar item.

Comment: If anybody having any sample code, then it will be helpful.